# PDF not showing page number in edge browser (First Time)

Tags: pdf, browser, microsoft-edge

I have PDF file when i open, it does not show the page numbers. When i do zoom IN or Zoom out, it start showing the page numbers.
I have checked Page zoom setting it is already 100%. 
Other browsers working fine regarding this issue.

What should i do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to view the local PDF file and the webpage which contains the PDF file using the legacy version Microsoft Edge and the latest version Microsoft Edge, they all showing the page number.

How do you view the PDF file in the Microsoft Edge, Directly open the Local PDF file using Microsoft Edge or view the PDF file in a web page? If you are viewing the PDF file on the web page, perhaps the issue is related to the code. Can you post the related code to reproduce the problem.

Besides, the issue might be related to the browser cache, you could try to clear the browser data (cache), and then recheck whether it works. If still not working, try to reset or repair Edge browser.